# Why does the Java implementation of Random.setSeed xor the parameter with 0x5DEECE66DL?

Tags: java, random

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed(long).  The code xors seed with the multiplier before reducing it mod 2^48.  Why not just reduce the passed seed mod 2^48?  The C equivalent seed48 does not perform the xor.

Comment: Why _not_ xor the seed with the multiplier?

Answer (score 4):

A nice read you can find here : [java.util.Random’s Magic Number 0x5DEECE66D](http://www.brettdaniel.com/archives/2009/04/09/154059/).

and a quote:

```
The analysis says it was chosen simply because researchers determined empirically 
that it produces a sequence of values satisfying various randomness tests
```

And this [Document](http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/java/random/README) gives a shot at the Magic number too.

and One more Quote:

> I then tried a search for the decimal value, excluding Java, and found
>   the answer in some class notes:

http://nut.bu.edu/~youssef/py502/monte_carlo_supplement.ps
    http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gaertner/texts/own_work/random_matrices.pdf

```
and in some computer documentation:
```

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/html/_rand48.3.html

```
The Youssef notes say:

... I can only say that 25214903917_LONG and 11_LONG have
apparently been chosen by passing a battery of such [meaning
Marsaglia's DIEHARD] tests.

... Even in the case of the 48-bit generators we are discussing
today, cas26 will generate them all in a month or two of CPU time
and then start to repeat.
```

Comment: The first link looks dead. The second one does not address the question, which is about the XOR operation in the `setSeed` method.